# Create Automation Action Group in Azure using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to use this command Set-AzActionGroup to action the standard automation runbook restart VM but there don't seem to be any examples of this around. To do this in Set-AzActionGroup I need to reference the VM, an automation account and some things called service uri and webhook resource id (which I think refers to the runbook). Has anyone got a fully specified example? I have a azure automation account but would need a webhook.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the PowerShell below to create an Action group with restart VM AutomationRunbookReceiver:

```
$automationAccountResourceGroup = ""
$automationAccountName = ""
$webhookName = "Webhook20210316" 
$receiverEmail = ""
$actionGroupName = ""

#create automationRunbookReceivers
$webhook = New-AzAutomationWebhook -Name $webhookName -IsEnabled $true -ExpiryTime "10/2/2030" -RunbookName "RestartAzureVmInResponseToVmAlertGlobalRunbook" -ResourceGroup $automationAccountResourceGroup -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName -Force
$serviceURI = $webhook.WebhookURI
$automationAccountID = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroup $automationAccountResourceGroup -name $automationAccountName).ResourceId
$WebhookResourceID  = $automationAccountID + "/webhooks/" + $webhook.name
$AutomationRunbookReceiver = New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name 'restartVM' -RunbookName 'Restart VM'  -AutomationAccountId $automationAccountID.ToLower() -IsGlobalRunbook -AutomationRunbookServiceUri $serviceURI -WebhookResourceId $WebhookResourceID 

#create email receivers
$EmailReceiver = New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name $receiverEmail -EmailReceiver -EmailAddress $receiverEmail

Set-AzActionGroup -ResourceGroupName $automationAccountResourceGroup -Name $actionGroupName -ShortName $actionGroupName -Receiver $EmailReceiver,$AutomationRunbookReceiver
```

**Result:**
[image]
[image]

**I also tested it on my side under some rules and it works as excepted:**

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me where you got RestartAzureVmInResponseToVmAlertGlobalRunbook from? Is there a list somewhere?

Comment: WebhookURI is not populated when I try it. Where are these web hooks in the automation account? I can't find them anywhere unless I create the runbook myself

Comment: Actually, to meet your requirement, I tried to capture all HTTPS requests from Azure portal for creating this kind of action group. All params and steps in powershell are based on this.  I also tried to search some doc about it, but the same , I have no result , LOL.

Comment: @johnstaveley, is there any exception info on your side ?

Comment: No, the webhook was created ok.

Comment: @johnstaveley,Ok , let me know if you have any questions and if my post is helpful, pls accept it as an answer :)

Comment: the webhook was fine, but because $webhook.WebhookURI was not set, the rest doesn't work

Comment: @johnstaveley, oh I just encounter this error on my side too, it works ok yesterday. But after I rename $webhookName, everything works as excepted, so could you pls try to rename it on your side? It should be unique.